# awaiting for aiofiles.os.remove() returns TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python-aiofiles

I'm trying to remove a file from a local directory asynchronously; however, I get the following error:
**object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression ()**

I'm using ver aiofiles 0.5.0 and Python 3.6.5

my code is as straightforward as such:

```
async def delete_local_file(file_to_del):
    await aiof.os.remove(file_to_del)
    print("deleted: "+file_to_del)

await delete_local_file(localfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

accidentally I used the wrong reference during import. simply use:
import aiofiles.os